# NativeScript : IOS app crashed on splash screen

Tags: xcode, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I am using `NativeScript` `6.0.2`, When I test app in simulator and real device its work fine. Then i archive project and uploaded `ipa` for `testFlight` successfully, But when i install app in device from `testFlight` its crashed on splash screen.

```
tns info

✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 6.0.2 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 6.0.3 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 6.1.0-2019-07-23-185153-03 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 6.0.1 version and is up to date.
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Here is the device log

[image]

I found some red path into Build Phases section(XCode), Is there any issues with them?

Here is the image of `Build Phases`

[image]

Comment: Are you creating a build for a device (signed with the proper provisioning profile)? Non-signed IPAs can not be deployed on a real device - only on a simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, After some investigation, I tried to prepare app for `Ios` using command `tns prepare ios --release` and then upload archive from XCode. Its worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will help but here is a tip, this is what I usually do when similar issues happen:

- Connect the device (iPhone) to your Mac.
- Open XCode and go to "Window > Devices & Simulators".
- Your device should be visible in the left pane under "Connected".
- Select the device, then on the right side you can either:

  - View Device Logs (check latest logs, perhaps you find some error here)
  - Open Console (open the console, then start the app, see what happens)

Hope it helps

Comment: That does not look like the entire stack-trace, there are parts missing. Look carefull through the loggs and see if it points to some parts of your app.

Comment: Okay, if i want to opne my project in Xcode, Which file i use? app.xcodeproj or app.xcworkspace?

Comment: Okay, Boss, I attached another image which i take into Build Phases from Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for what exact reason but I was facing the same exact issue as well. But after using `tns prepare ios --release` this worked and there's no crashing issue once build.